# Partial pull from git bundle

Tags: git, git-bundle

I'm trying to pull a subset of a git bundle into a repo.

### Setup

Starting with this repo.

```
R1: A --> B --> C --> D --> E --> F
```

I've created these git bundles

```
# git bundle create B1 C..E
# git bundle create B1 B..F

B1:       C --> D --> E
B2: B --> C --> D --> E --> F
```

I've created a shallow clone, depth 1, from C

```
# git clone --depth 1 file:///R1 R2
R2: C
```

### Pulling bundles

From R2 I can pull from B1 to get:

```
# git pull B1 main
R2: C --> D --> E
```

But when I'm trying to pull from B2 I get this error message

```
# git pull B2 main
error: Repository lacks these prerequisite commits:
error: B
```

Which is true, R2 does not have commit B.

Is there a way to have it ignore B and only fill up from C and get this?:

```
R2: C --> D --> E --> F
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one bundle for each commit.
Here we move the branch "main" so that each bundle have the same branch to pull from.

```
#B3: A --> B
git branch -f main B
git bundle create ../B3 A..main
#B4: B --> C
git branch -f main C
git bundle create ../B4 B..main
#B5: C --> D
git branch -f main D
git bundle create ../B5 C..main
#B6: D --> E
git branch -f main E
git bundle create ../B6 D..main
#B7: E --> F
git branch -f main F
git bundle create ../B7 E..F
```

Then pull from them in order.

```
git pull B3 main
git pull B4 main
git pull B5 main
git pull B6 main
git pull B7 main
```

You can skip pulling B3 (A-->B) and B4 (B-->C) since they will fail anyway.